# CRM 2011 Dialog - Open the entity created in a Dialog

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a Dialog that creates an opportunity.

At the end of the Dialog I would like the new opportunity to open.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you create the Opportunity via your dialog, show a Page. In the Prompt Text or Tip Text, click the "Insert Hyperlink" button - then in the URL field, select the Opportunity entity in the drop-down list then "Record URL(Dynamic)" in the field selector.